# How to edit TTS pronunciations on Mac using RegExs

Tags: macos, text-to-speech

I use Mac's built in Text-to-Speech engine quite a lot and on the whole am impressed with its quality. However I would very much like to be able to specify my own customisations using regular expressions, such as including a substitution similar to: `"\[\d+\]" -> ""` to prevent quotation indexes on Wikipedia pages being read aloud.

I know there is a pronunciation override for the "VoiceOver" feature however this feature does not accept regular expression syntax and does not seem to take effect in the general (hotkey) "Speech" feature anyhow.

I see there are options for using different voices and modifying the readback speed but is there a way to manipulate the text that is being spoken before it gets handed to the engine?

Note: To be clear I'm talking about the TTS feature that can be activated with:

`Apple Icon > System Preferences > Accessibility > Speech > Speak Selected Text When the Key is Pressed`

rather than the "VoiceOver" feature that automatically speaks the screen to you.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to build your own "apple clipboard regex manipulator" app.  You need to find a way to manipulate the text after it's selected and before it gets sent to the tts.